# 1231 - Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, importerror

I was importing Zip file containing multiple .sql file
during import its give me following error

```
1231 - Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
```

Someone already posted solution that i have to add following line in start of mysqldump file

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

**But i could not found Mysqldump file in my Ubuntu 18.04 Please tell me location of this file**

Comment: I have removed the sql server tag, this question is clearly not about sql-server but about mysql

Comment: Considering that SQL Server doesn't have an error code 1231, and that MySQL's error 1231 is the one in the title, it seems this is MySQL, *not* SQL Server. Please don't add unrelated tags or conflicting tag to the question.

Comment: @Larnu i am new to this field so i don't know much about this sorry i did not added these tag intentionally i got this error in phpmyadmin